# Odd tabular first line justification behavior

Tags: tables, spacing

So I have the following table:

```
\begin{tabular}{l | r}\label{tab:cost}
    Budget Item & Cost \\
    \hline{}
    Books & \$825 \\
    Room/Board & \$12,100 \\
    Personal & \$2,265 \\
    Transportation & \$400 \\
    Resident Tutition & \$11,000
\end{tabular}
```

And the justification for the left hand side of the first line is a bit off as seen in the following image:

[image: Books is not properly aligned]

Note the space before the word 'books' in that table. Is there any way to remove that space? I tried forcing a line break after the horizontal line with `\\` which fixes the alignment of books, but that adds a bit of vertical space that I'd rather not have.

[image: Books is properly aligned, but there is a bit of whitespace that I'd rather not have]

Thnaks in advance,
Avi Caspe

PS: if it helps I am using TeXMaker on Windows, installed from the MiKTeX site. I doubt that matters, but it may.

Comment: `\hline` does not take an argument, so don't use `\hline{}`, but `\hline` instead. `{}` together with the line ending inserts a spurious space at the start of the `Books` cell.

Answer (score 2):

The solution to your problem is very simple.

All you have to do is eliminate the {} after \hline.

Your code then will be

```
\begin{tabular}{l | r}\label{tab:cost}
    Budget Item & Cost \\ \hline
    Books & \$825 \\
    Room/Board & \$12,100 \\
    Personal & \$2,265 \\
    Transportation & \$400 \\
    Resident Tutition & \$11,000
\end{tabular}
```

As a result, you will get
[image: Table without {} after \hline]

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Why is this an issue at all? Why does an extra set of curly braces cause this issue?

Comment: @AviCaspe: See [my comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/406819/odd-tabular-first-line-justification-behavior#comment1014417_406819) and also [What is the use of percent signs (`%`) at the end of lines?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764)

Comment: @AviCaspe A line of code ending on a macro name (like `\hline`) does not see the end-of-line as a trailing space (in essence, the end-of-line is absorbed as the terminator to the macro name); where as a line of code that ends on a normal character, such as `}` will see the end-of-line as a space, unless you trail the line with a `%` immediately after the `}`.